# showcmd on first line instead of last line

Tags: options

From the help file for showcmd:

> Show (partial) command in the last line of the screen

Is it possible to have the commands displayed on the first line instead? I can't find anything in the help or on the web on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

Since [Vim 9.0.1061](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/11684) (Dec 2022) you can use `showcmdloc=tabline` to display the showcmd in the tabline (assuming that is what's intended with "first line"). You can also use `showcmd=statusline`, or use `%S` in the 'statusline' or 'tabline' settings.

Neovim seems to [have ported this patch](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/21202), but it's not in any release at the time of writing. Presumably it will be in the upcoming 0.9 release.

For older versions you're out of luck, as it's all hard-coded.

Comment: inclunded in Neovim 0.9   https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/040f1459849ab05b04f6bb1e77b3def16b4c2f2b/runtime/doc/news.txt