# Can you read the value of `showcmd` in a vimscript function?

Tags: vimscript

I don't know how to make any vimscript I'm writing or running aware of what my pending command is!

Specifically: When I hit `^W` in preparation to change the window I'm selecting, I'd like to have my statusbar reflect that.

Comment: You can check the value of the option in an expression using `&showcmd`, but that just tells you whether its on or off—afaik there’s no way to tell what’s already been typed. (You *could* create a mapping.. i might have an idea for you there. )

Comment: A mapping would work to add state, and maybe a BufEnter autocmd to remove state would work... I don’t love how hacky that is though :P

Comment: No, i would map control w to do what it normally does plus whatever you want to do

Comment: Very similar: [Can I see the history of key presses in normal mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/570/51) and [showcmd on first line instead of last line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16857/51) – last time I looked at this the answer was "no, this isn't possible" as far as I could figure out (see my answer on that last one).

Comment: Like you said, a mapping could work, but I can't really think of a good way to clear the state without redefining a lot of mappings. The way `^W<key>` works internally btw is that `^W` is mapped and then it has a long `switch (second_key) { ... }` for the second key press to call the correct functionality. It's all pretty hard-coded in a non-generic way.