# Make keypresses stay in the bottom-right until the next action

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

Say I type **ciw** then it will show **c** then **ci** then blank. Is it possible to keep it there until I start a new sequence of commands?
I'm assuming that since a lot of videos I see use an overlay logging key presses, this is not a feature.

Comment: `set notimeout` or `set timeoutlen=10000` ... but at your own risk :)

Comment: Not sure if I misunderstood you or you misunderstood me, but I mean that once a command has been typed successfully, the text showing the characters typed disappears and I was wondering if I can preserve the text until the next command (only saying that since the 2 commands do nothing in relation to my problem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing command history with showcmd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/742/showing-command-history-with-showcmd)

Comment: See also this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16858/343 (The question is slightly different, but the answer also applies to your question.)